# Python translate a column with multiple languages to english

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, translation, google-translate

I have a dataset where there are multiple comments columns having multiple languages and I want to translate these columns into English and create new columns with all the english translations.

**Accountability_COMMENT** is the column which has multiple comments in different language in every row. I want to create a new column and translate all such comments to English.

I have tried the following code :

```
 from googletrans import Translator
 from textblob import TextBlob
 translator = Translator()
 data_merge['Accountability_COMMENT'] = data_merge['Accountability_COMMENT'].apply(lambda x: 
 TextBlob(x).translate(to='en'))
```

The error that I am getting is :

TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not class 'float'

My column has objet format which is correct

Comment: You have tried that code... and? Do you get any error? The output doesn't look like the one you want?

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me how your input DataFrame looks like, and how the output one should look like. Is there *one* column with the comments, or are there *many* columns with comments?

Comment: there is one column that contains about 3000 comments all in different languages.. I need to translate all of them to english and store them into a new column..

Comment: I tested your code on a test DataFrame with just three rows with strings in different languages and it worked. What does the error message actually say? `TypeError: The text argument passed to __init__(text) must be a string, not` what? What is after the `not`?

Comment: TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'float'>

Answer (score 3):

You most probably have some comments that only consists of a `float` (i.e. a decimal number), that even if they are `type: object` according to `pandas` they are still interpreted as `float` by `TextBlob`. This leads to the error:

```
TypeError: The text argument passed to __init__(text) must be a string, not <class 'float'>
```

One solution is to make sure that the input `x` of `TextBlob(x)` is a string. You could do this by modifying the `apply` row like:

```
 data_merge['Accountability_COMMENT'] = data_merge['Accountability_COMMENT'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(str(x)).translate(to='en'))
```

Unfortunately this will probably also rais an error like:

```
raise NotTranslated('Translation API returned the input string unchanged.')
textblob.exceptions.NotTranslated: Translation API returned the input string unchanged.
```

This is due to the fact that when translating a number, the translation and the original text will be exactly the same, and apparently `TextBlob` doesn't like that.

What you can do to avoid this is to catch that exception `NotTranslated` and just return the untranslated `TextBlob`, like this:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob.exceptions import NotTranslated    

def translate_comment(x):
    try:
        # Try to translate the string version of the comment
        return TextBlob(str(x)).translate(to='en')
    except NotTranslated:
        # If the output is the same as the input just return the TextBlob version of the input
        return TextBlob(str(x))

data_merge['Accountability_COMMENT'] = data_merge['Accountability_COMMENT'].apply(translate_comment)
```

**EDIT:**
If you get the HTTP error `Too Many Requests` it's probably because you are being kicked out by the Google Translate API. Instead of using `apply`, you can make your translation "extra-slow" by using a `for` loop with some sleep in-between cycles. In this case you should import another package (`time`) and substitute the last line:

```
from time import sleep
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob.exceptions import NotTranslated    

def translate_comment(x):
    try:
        # Try to translate the string version of the comment
        return TextBlob(str(x)).translate(to='en')
    except NotTranslated:
        # If the output is the same as the input just return the TextBlob version of the input
        return TextBlob(str(x))

for i in range(len(data_merge['Accountability_COMMENT'])):
    # Translate one comment at a time
    data_merge['Accountability_COMMENT'].iloc[i] = translate_comment(data_merge['Accountability_COMMENT'].iloc[i])

    # Sleep for a quarter of second
    sleep(0.25)
```

You can then experiment with different values for the `sleep` function. Of course the longer the sleep the slower the translation! N.B. `sleep` argument is in seconds.

Comment: This looks really prpmosing and makes sense to me. But still I have got an error :HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests. I am not sure how to tackle this one.

Comment: I edited my answer, hopefully it helps. If you found my answer to be useful please upvote it, and if it solved your problem please accept! :)

Comment: I am still getting the same error.. I did the try and except thing in a different cell and then the time import thing in a different one. Still I am receiving the same error..

Comment: And once we overcome this error, in the same dataframe, I have about 10 more columns on whichI need to do the same thing.

Comment: You have two *separate* problems that need to be solved at the same time if you want all the code to work. One is about the wrong type in some of the cells, and one is about the too many requests `textblob` is making (under the hood) to the Google. Please see my updated code, you have to use *both* the function with the exception and the for loop with the `sleep` function. I don't think I can do much more than this to help you, this should have already pointed you on the correct track.